# how to release presentModalViewController from stack Memory in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am currently working on  a project in which I  am calling other view through below way through out the project  :---

```
frmImage *frmImageOne = [[frmImage alloc]initWithNibName:@"frmImage" bundle:nil]; 
[self presentModalViewController:frmImageOne animated:YES];
[frmImageOne release];
```

Exactly  what I want is that when I load my application in IPhone device it gets terminated due to StackOverflow by presentModalViewController.that is nothing but memory leakage .

So please can any body tel me how to release presentModelViewcontroller from stack memory through codes.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'd look in your viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear or other setup code for the modal controller to make sure that the super's implementation is called.

Answer (score 2):

Stack overflow has nothing to do with memory leakage, and you're not storing `frmImage` on the stack. ObjC can't store objects on the stack. It only stores pointers on the stack; objects themselves are always stored on the heap in ObjC.

If you're getting a stack overflow, then you're almost certainly in an infinite recursion loop. Is your stack trace hundreds or thousands of frames deep of the same calls? That's the usual cause.